# How to define global variable in PL/SQL in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I define a global variable in PL/SQL which will be available in all functions / procedures / packages?

Is it possible to define?

Or is there any alternate way to do this?

Comment: Do you want the value of this global variable to be shared among all sessions or do you want it to be private to each session?

Comment: I recall there was a way how to store package state variables in SGA or UGA? (not in PGA) and then package state was shared between sessions. But I can not any reference about this in docs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create new package with your variable in package specification, like this:

```
CREATE PACKAGE my_public_package IS
  my_var Number;
END;
```

Now you can access variable in any code with access to my_public_package

```
...
my_public_package.my_var := 10;
...
```

Comment: you can use a pl/sql associative array to implement a global hash table in this way

Comment: this variable is session scoped

Comment: The OP asked for a *GLOBAL* method, and if a s @PavelGatnar says this is local/session, then this is not a valid answer (I need to know same and specifically how to set global)

Comment: Packages are instantiated per session.
Use table.

Answer (score 11):

> How can I define a global variable in PL/SQL which will be available in all functions / procedures / packages?

You could use a [Global Application Context variable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/app_context.htm#DBSEG011).

> An application context is a set of name-value pairs that Oracle
>   Database stores in memory. The application context has a label called
>   a namespace, for example, empno_ctx for an application context that
>   retrieves employee IDs. Inside the context are the name-value pairs
>   (an associative array): the name points to a location in memory that
>   holds the value. An application can use the application context to
>   access session information about a user, such as the user ID or other
>   user-specific information, or a client ID, and then securely pass this
>   data to the database. You can then use this information to either
>   permit or prevent the user from accessing data through the
>   application. You can use application contexts to authenticate both
>   database and nondatabase users.

If you want that the v**ariable value should be same across all the sessions for any PL/SQL object accessing the variable**, then use a **database table** to store the value.

For example, as T.Kyte suggests [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:1578344046713)

```
CREATE TABLE global_value(x INT);

INSERT INTO global_value VALUES (0);

COMMIT;

CREATE OR replace PACKAGE get_global
AS
  FUNCTION Val
  RETURN NUMBER;
  PROCEDURE set_val (
    p_x IN NUMBER );
END;

/

CREATE OR replace PACKAGE BODY get_global
AS
  FUNCTION Val
  RETURN NUMBER
  AS
    l_x NUMBER;
  BEGIN
      SELECT x
      INTO   l_x
      FROM   global_value;

      RETURN l_x;
  END;
  PROCEDURE Set_val(p_x IN NUMBER)
  AS
    PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
  BEGIN
      UPDATE global_value
      SET    x = p_x;

      COMMIT;
  END;
END;

/
```

Comment: you should make the table, getter and setter more general to store key-value pairs, 1 table for 1 value is an overkill

Comment: *One table for one value?* Where did you see I said one table per value anywhere? It is just one table for a global variable value. Understand before commenting and down-voting. You know this is the solution provide by Thomas Kyte? https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:1578344046713

Comment: Why the `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` in `Set_val`?

Comment: Because you want the update to happen for sure even though other programs fail. Because you want to set the context.

Comment: 1. ok, so you have 1 column for 1 variable (not mentioned in your answer). then it is ok. you should only adjust your getter and setter names ... then I will upvote your answer  2. you should reference the source, if it is not your idea

Comment: Oops, I thought I added the reference link, anyway added it now. And regarding one value one column, OP asked about A VARIABLE, so this example is based on A VARIABLE and not multiple variables and their respective values. I think the solution above is for both cases, same session as well as multiple sessions. Not sure what does a downvote mean.

Comment: btw. heard about `RESULT CACHE`?

Comment: Query or function? btw, the value needs to be static. Isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

```
variable_name [CONSTANT] datatype [NOT NULL] [:= | DEFAULT initial_value]
```